# 302 found - Facebook share button

Tags: facebook, http-status-code-302, mod-security, share-button

This is my first post here so Im gonna try to make it as clear as possible.
Our client's website(we didn't developed this one) is passing through our firewall(modsecurity).
They have an facebook share button in their blog, so when you hit the button, it asks for your facebook account normally, and then a facebook sharing pop-up is opened with this message:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uk1lP.jpg

[302 found]

You can share the post in your profile anyway, but our client is complaining a lot about it d-.-b.

I already deactivated our firewall for test-only, and the message persists.

Does someone has any idea about how to "fix it", or if its a server misconfiguration or code problem?

Comment: What is the url of the page? Have you tried running it through the debugger at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: @WizKid I have tried what you said and I got this: Critical Errors That Must Be Fixed: Could Not Follow Redirect: URL requested a HTTP redirect, but it could not be followed.   Errors That Must Be Fixed: Missing Required Property: The 'og:type' property is required, but not present.  Do you have any idea how can I fix it? I'm sorry, I'm a newbie... Here is the URL of the page: http://www.upprj.com/index.php/acontece/acontece-selecionado/programacaeo-especial-para-as-maees-de-comunidades-pacificadas/CPP

Comment: The problem is that you are sending back a redirect to the same url

Comment: @WizKid this website is passing through a firewall (modsecurity@ubuntu), do you think this firewall could cause this redirect problem, or this is just a simple code issue?

Comment: Sounds strange that the firewall would do a redirect to the same page.